# Django Image Upload: IOErrno2 Could not find path -- and yet it's saving the image there anyway?

Tags: python, django, image, upload, ioerror

I have an issue where the local version of Django is handling image upload as expected but my server is not.  Note: I am using a Django Container on MediaTemple.net (grid server)

Here is my code.

```
def view_settings(request):    
<snip>
if request.POST:
    success_msgs = ()
    mForm = MainProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = mProfile)
    pForm = ChangePasswordForm(request.POST)
    eForm = ChangeEmailForm(request.POST)
    if mForm.is_valid():
        m = mForm.save(commit = False)
        if mForm.cleaned_data['avatar']:
            m.avatar = upload_photo(request.FILES['avatar'], settings.AVATAR_SAVE_LOCATION)
        m.save()
        success_msgs += ('profile pictured updated',)
            <snip>

def upload_photo(data,saveLocation):
    savePath = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, saveLocation, data.name) 
    destination = open(savePath, 'wb+')
    for chunk in data.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
    return os.path.join(saveLocation, data.name)
```

Here's where it gets whacky and I was hoping someone could shed a light on this error, because either

- it's the wrong error code, or
- something is happening with the file before it's completely handled.

To recap, the file was actually uploaded to the server in the intended directory - and yet this err msg continues to persist.

> IOError at /user/settings
>
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> u'/home/user66666/domains/example.com/html/media/images/avatars/DSC03852.JPG'
>
> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL:
> http://111.111.111.111:2011/user/settings
> Django Version: 1.0.2 final Python
> Version: 2.4.4 Installed Applications:
> ['django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
> 'django.contrib.sessions',
> 'django.contrib.sites',  'ctrlme',
> 'usertools',  'easy_thumbnails']
> Installed Middleware:
> ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
> "/home/user6666/containers/django/leonidas/usertools/views.py"
> in view_settings
> 51.                 m.avatar = upload_photo(request.FILES['avatar'],
> settings.AVATAR_SAVE_LOCATION) File
> "/home/user666666/containers/django/leonidas/usertools/functions.py"
> in upload_photo
> 91.     destination = open(savePath, 'wb+')

Comment: What FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS do you use? Default?

Comment: It's been modified for Grid server. FLock as opposed to LockF

Comment: What's your settings.AVATAR_SAVE_LOCATION? I think it's wrong.